What is the best way to deal with protoc generated file with docker?
I am using Docker to manage my ROS environment, and I recreate the Docker container each time I run it. When I first run catkin_make on my ROS package, protoc generates some files that are stored in the system directory of the Docker container. However, these files are lost when I recreate the container, and subsequent attempts to run catkin_make fail because it doesn't regenerate those files, leading to errors.
What is the best approach to manage these generated files? Should I store them in a local directory that persists across container runs, or should I modify the build process so catkin_make regenerates the files each time I start a new container?

I'd normally expect the build process to run in the Dockerfile, so just once when you build the image and not once every time you run the container.  You should not typically use volumes or mounted directories to hold code or other artifacts of the build process.
